# Match pattern so long as it doesn't contain a specific string

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds

Let's say I have the following strings:

`quiz.1.player.chat_results`
and 
`partner_quiz.1.player.chat_results`

I have hundreds of strings like this where the only difference is that one is prefixed with "partner" and the other is not.  I'm trying to match one but not the other.

The specific pattern I'd like to match looks like so:

```
index <- grep('^(quiz.)[1-5]{1}.player.chat_results', names(data))
```

But this will match both strings.  I'm guessing I have to use some negative lookahead like so:

```
^((?!partner).)
```

But I'm not sure where to use it.

Comment: Or you can keep using `grep` with `invert = TRUE` to grep _non-matching_ strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach: use `str_detect` from stringr

```
> library(stringr)
> str_detect(string, "partner", negate=TRUE)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

You can even use one `grepl` and negate the result

```
> !grepl("partner", string)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Just for fun: you can split the string using as separator `\\.` or `_` and then iterate over each element of the resulting list comparing each element to `partner` and finally invert the result

```
> sapply(strsplit(string, "\\.|_"), function(x) !"partner" %in%  x)
[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 7):

I'll answer your title question, as it will be the most useful to other people finding this question.

How to match strings that do *not* contain a given pattern? Easy, match the pattern and invert it.

```r
index <- grep('^partner', names(data), invert = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use two `grepl` to avoid any confusion

```
grepl('quiz', names(data)) & !grepl('partner', names(data))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

For someone who is a bit regex-blind like myself, `sub` can help,

```
sub('_.*', '', x) == 'partner'
#[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Ah, this is super useful. Was trying to think of how to do this without Regex.

Comment: You can avoid all regex and use `strsplit` on the underscore and loop over the list it outputs and check the first entry. I ll edit it in my answer asap.

Comment: @Parseltongue check my answer, last alternvative avoids regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match the pattern including the digits, you could use a word boundary `\b` followed by a negative lookahead `(?!partner)` to assert what is directly on the right is not partner.

Note to  escape the dot to match it literally and you can omit `{1}`. If you are not the value of the captured group around quiz, you might omit it as well.

To match the rest of the string, you might use `\S+` to match not a non whitespace char.

```
\b(?!partner)quiz\.[1-5]\.player\S*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YAnWXc/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/y374ZP)

For example

```
regmatches(txt1,regexpr("\\b(?!partner)quiz\\.[1-5]\\.player\\S*",txt, per=TRUE))
```